# Software like total commander

Tags: software-recommendation

Is there any software in ubuntu which is similar than total commander, I tried Krusader, but that is too weak, don't have that many features that TC.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[10 Total Commander Alternatives for Linux](http://168hours.wordpress.com/2008/08/18/10-total-commander-alternatives-for-linux/)

It's a three years old the post, but I don't think it is a problem.

A recommended file manager for Linux from Total Commander site is Krusader.